# Using Column Header as Argument in Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

I have a two tables which simplified down to

Table Name: Quiz

| ID | Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 92 | 75 |
| 1 | 88 | 81 |

And another table

Table Name: Summary

| ID | Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `=XLOOKUP([@[ID]],Quiz[ID],Quiz[Q1])` | `=XLOOKUP([@[ID]],Quiz[ID],Quiz[Q2])` |
| 1 | `=XLOOKUP([@[ID]],Quiz[ID],Quiz[Q1])` | `=XLOOKUP([@[ID]],Quiz[ID],Quiz[Q2])` |

I would like a way to replace Q1 and Q2 in the formula with a reference to the header so that they could use the exact same formula in all the cells.

Side Notes: My motivation to use XLOOKUP is that the tables may be sorted differently.

The columns may also be out of order, thus the structured references.

Answer (score 1):

If you use INDEX/MATCH and Absolute referencing you can create the formula an point it at the header of the first, then drag it over.

```
=XLOOKUP(Table4[@[ID]:[ID]],Quiz[[ID]:[ID]],INDEX(Quiz,0,MATCH(Table4[[#Headers],[Q1]],Quiz[#Headers],0)))
```

[image]

Now, no matter the order in the the result table it will refer to the correct column, and as the titles are updated the formula will auto update:

[image]

---

Edit:

To remove any actual reference to that actual header and make it so it will work in any column:

```
=XLOOKUP(Table4[@[ID]:[ID]],Quiz[[ID]:[ID]],INDEX(Quiz,0,MATCH(INDEX(Table4[#Headers],COLUMN()-MIN(COLUMN(Table4[#Headers]))+1),Quiz[#Headers],0)))
```

Comment: I like this answer; I definitely learned something from it.  It doesn't quite do what I wanted in having the same formula for each cell.  I am not sure what I want is even possible.